# "no usable version of libssl was found" with .NET 5 on Heroku-22 stack

Tags: .net, heroku, libssl

My app is working fine with the Heroku0-20 stack, but when I upgrade to stack 22, I get "No usable version of libssl was found". I am using .NET Core 5, and it likely means I need libssl.

How can I install it on the Heroku dyno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 (Focal) - what the Heroku-22 stack is based off - upgraded to **OpenSSL 3.0** which is not supported by .net 5. You will need to either upgrade .net to some `7.x` version ([it appears based on GitHub issue details](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46526)) or install **OpenSSL 1.x.y** in your stack so its present for your .net program to find it.

Answer (score 4):

You can run this command with heroku CLI to revert back to stack Heroku-20

```
heroku stack:set heroku-20 -a your-app-name
```

Comment: This worked for me, I'm using .net core 3.1.x and I couldn't upgrade, so I just reverted the stack.